# Java heap space error when migrating to Visual Studio Online using OpsHub Migration Tool

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm trying to use the OpsHub migration tool to get our source code onto Visual Studio Online. Partway through the migration, the progress page indicates an error occurred and that the migration has halted, and yet the process still continues to run (ie - Migration Status still says it's Running, and process manager indicates work is still being done by the opshubtfsservice.exe process).

If I click on the hyper link in the error message, it opens a popup dialog indicating there's been a Java heap space error of some kind. Looking closer at running processes, I can see the Java.exe process is using up over 2GB of RAM. I'm running the migration tool on a Windows 7 x64 machine with 16GB of RAM and loads of disc space free. Source server is running TFS 2013.

I've run the tool a few times now, and run into the same issue right at the same point during the migration (xxxx/yyyy Chageset(s)/Label(s) passed). It doesn't seem to get to xxxx+1/yyyy, but perhaps I just need to let it run longer as it's likely chewing on some large changeset of somekind.

Any suggestions on how, or if it's possible to get passed this error? Should I be concerned about it, or just roll with it and see what happens if I let the process continue?

Answer (score 1):

By default the migration utility is restricted to using 2GB of memory.

Please follow the following steps to allow it to use more memory.

1) Close application

2) Go to \OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\OpsHubServer6.0.16\bin (Installation Drive may be: C:\Program Files)

3) Open service.bat in NotePad. Find following string "-Xmx2048m". Replace -Xmx2048m to -Xmx4096m (or the appropriate number for the max memory size)

4) Save file

5) In same folder

Run *unregisterservice.bat* as administrator (Which will unregister OpsHub service. Verify by opening *services.msc* there will be no "OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility" service)

Run *registerservice.bat* as administrator (Which will register OpsHub service. Verify by opening *services.msc* and there will be "OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility" service with "Automatic" startup type)

6) Open *services.msc*, Right click on "OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility" , Click on properties, select startup type "Manual" click on "Apply"

7) Start application which will now use 4096m memory (4 GB) or whatever amount specified in step 3

Comment: This seems to have helped indeed. I've had a few more failed attempts as memory got maxed out. I've now set the process to allow up to 14GB of RAM usage. The process is still running, but java.exe is now sitting at 13.3 GB for the working set, and the process is running quite slowly. I only got through maybe 20 changesets today, and there's still another 600 to go. Crossing my fingers that it'll speed up and complete, but based on current rate and memory usage it's feeling like it might be a stretch.

Comment: Couldn't get our code migrated. The code base I am migrating is quite large, but we've only be using TFS onsite since January (6 months) and we've only accumulated just over 4000 change sets. The migration goes so slowly that it would take days, or maybe even weeks to complete. And that's assuming I'm there right when the tool runs out of memory. Even with 14GB of RAM set to be used, the process still failed with memory related errors. Looks like we'll be loosing our history and just check everything in to VSO from the tip of our TFS tree.

Comment: @Opshub: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262729/reach-out-to-opshub-about-outsourcing-their-support-to-stack-overflow