# OpsHub System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: .net, azure-devops, opshub

Im trying to migrate a TFS team project to VSO with no success. I always get the System.OutOfMemoryException. I followed the following thread in hope to increase the memory for the Java runtime.
[Java heap space error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944779/java-heap-space-error-when-migrating-to-visual-studio-online-using-opshub-migrat)

This is the error message if I look in the EventLog:

```
Application: opshubtfsservice.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)
   at System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.IOCompleted(System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult, UInt32, UInt32)
   at System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

When I look how much memory actually being used it's far from the 32 GB that my server has.

Is there any way to get more info on why the OpsHub TFS Service crashes?

Have anyone experienced this and fixed it?

**My setup is the following:**

OpsHub: Version-1.0 OpsHub Integration Manager Framework-OVSMU-V1.0.1008

OS: Windows Server 2012 Standard 64-bit

.NET CLR Available: 4.0.30319 and below (32 and 64 bit)

The error does not occur at a particular changeset. When I look at the migration progress in OpsHub VSO Migration Utility I can see that the Work Item "Reading and analysis" and "Migration" is "Running". Version Control is "Not Running".

Are there any logfiles I can look into?

Comment: This Question has nothing to do with Java, you are using .net on the CLR.

Comment: Do you use a 64bit CLR? The 32bit version is restricted to 1.5GB heap.

Comment: Hi Andreas. Sorry to hear that. Could you provide more details on your environment(OS, Architecture, CLR Version and Architecture) as well as the point of this failure during the migration? At a particular changeset or length of time?

Comment: Hi Andreas. We would be releasing a new version of out Utility where we have fixed this problem. The utility would now be able to leverage memory better on x64 bit machines. We'll update you in a day, once the release it out. Thanks

Comment: Great! Looking forward to it. We really need to migrate our projects.

Comment: Hi, Andreas. Thank you for your patience. We would be releasing the new build today.

Comment: Use the TFS Integration Platform if you really need it to work...